# Sencha ExtJS 6.5.1 - Dynamic package dependency

Tags: extjs, extjs6.5.1

I'm using dynamic package feature ("uses") to load packages dynamically in a classic toolkit app.

However, the dynamic package requires additional classes from another packages.

Building the app in production mode does not include those additional files (from second package) in the combined package file.

How can I add the required classes into the dynamic package build.

```
App
requires: ['packageA'],
uses: ['packageB']

PackageB
requires: ['packageA']
```

Currently only those classes are included (from packageA) which are requires by the App but not the once that are required in PackageB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I was able to find a problem.  I was using old style .sencha directory in the app which was using old build.xml file.  I removed .sencha directory and updated the build.xml file from the latest ExtJS examples and it started to work correctly.

Now all dependencies from PackageA are loaded properly into app.js file.